# swift count elements in dictionary value for tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

i have variable of type [Int: [CustomObject]], and i need to count [CustomObject].count by key in my numberOfRowsInSection ? how can i access this value ?

```
var tasks = [Int :[TaskEntity]]()
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("section: \(section), taskKey: \(tasks.keys.sorted())") 
}
```

Like each key in dict has an array of elements as value, i need to count this elements in array for each key-value pair

**UPD**: I'he added print line as Joakim Danielson suggested. Print says:

When i add cell to section 0: "section: 0, taskKey: []
section: 0, taskKey: [0]"

When i add cell to section 1: "section: 1, taskKey: [0, 1]
section: 0, taskKey: [0, 1]"

Now i'm confused about output

Comment: if `section` corresponds to the key in the dictionary you could do `tasks[section, default: []].count`

Comment: you mean with dict.keys.contains(key) ? Not works for me :(

`if tasks.keys.contains(section) { tasks[section, default: []].count  }`

Comment: Then what does the key in the dictionary represent?

Comment: key is an index of section where i want to show cells

Comment: Then it should work but you don't need the `contains` part. Otherwise the keys in the `tasks` dictionary does not represent the sections and then you need to investigate why.

Comment: Why don't you add `print(section, tasks.keys.sorted())`at the beginning of `tableView(_, numberOfRowsInSection:)`and check if the numbers are what you expect.

Comment: Please watch my code block update

Comment: Then it looks like my suggested solution should work fine.

Comment: You could have an array containing the sorted dictionary keys. So get section key from this array then rows count using number of tasks for section key.

Comment: Please do not edit the answer into your question, but post an answer instead.